# Dropping the annotation (Pin) on the current location

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, mkmapview

I am trying to drop an annotation on the current location but it is not getting dropped. How can it be possible to drop the annotation on the current location and store that location in SQLite. For dropping annotation on the current location. I am trying this from two days but not getting any success.

Does anyone have any idea or link or hints to solve that?

Comment: @Joinathan leffler how i can do is that any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this code:-

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{

    if (annotation == mapView.userLocation)
    {

        MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil];
        annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        annView.animatesDrop=TRUE;
        annView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
        return annView;
        [annView release];



    }
}
```

Comment: I want to how can drop the annotation on current location And store that location into sqlite database

Comment: @Ajay this is the code for annotation drop and you can get the latitude and longitude from mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude and mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude and then you can store them in your sqlite database.

Comment: I need to store the location where the my annotation is droped . want store that location in to the sqlite database